# python setup.py develop not updating easy_install.pth

Tags: python, setuptools

According to [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#development-mode) documentation, setup.py develop is supposed to create the egg-link file and update easy_install.pth when installing into site-packages folder.  However, in my case it's only creating the egg-link file.  How does setuptools decide if it needs to update easy_install.pth?

Some more info:
It works when I have setuptools 0.6c7 installed as a folder under site-packages.  But when I use setuptools 0.6c9 installed as a zipped egg, it does not work.

Comment: Which OS is this on? Python version?

Comment: Works for me on Linux, Python 2.4, setuptools-0.6c9dev_r0-py2.4.egg unzipped. You can't import the installed package?

Answer (score 4):

Reinstall setuptools with the command `easy_install --always-unzip --upgrade setuptools`. If that fixes it then the zipping was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to debug it with pdb. The issue is most likely with the easy install's method check_site_dir, which seeks for easy-install.pth.

Comment: When debugging a zipped egg with pdb, won't you get an error when you try to single-step into the zipped code?

Comment: I have no clue. Maybe you would. But you are right, the first thing to try would be to reinstall the setuptools as you've said.